rqt_graph sees more nodes and topics than ros2 topic list and ros2 node list
I'm migrating a ROS1 application to ROS2 and am at the stage where I have some nodes converted and running. The main workhorse node, though, runs fine (as in not crashing) but it doesn't show up when I ros2 node list, and its topics don't show up with the command ros2 topic list, not even with ros2 topic list --include-hidden-topics
But it shows up in rqt_graph with its topics just fine (8 topics and a transform broadcaster) as long as deadsinks are not hidden. The missing topics also show up in rqt's topic monitor (though it seems laggy). If I check the topics in monitor - they actually work. I can see the values coming in and the update rate.
Here is the weirdest thing. If I start monitoring a topic in rqt, then it will now show up in ros2 topic list and I can echo those topics. But the unchecked ones remain missing and ros2 node list still doesn't report the existence of the node, even though it's there in rqt_graph the whole time.
This is all on a single system with no special config of the default DDS. Foxy on Focal. It's a c++ node with only publishers active at the moment.
How is it that rqt can see this node and its topics, but nothing else can? ros2 doctor doesn't show the topics either - until they are "activated" by rqt topic monitor.

This issue seems resolved. The problem was likely just performance. I turned off all the packet logging I was doing (quite a bit - for debugging a different problem) and topic publishing started working. The node became visible too.
My guess is that the extreme logging was causing a lot of lag in topic responsiveness and rqt seems to have a more patient and persistent approach to discovering running topics than the ros2 command line utilities.
I still don't understand how rqt's topic monitor seemed to "activate" the topics for peer applications.

Regarding your last line, if you have a follow-up question then please ask a new question.
